# MacOS RStudio accessing wrong clang after upgrade to Catalina

Tags: clang, rstudio, macos-catalina

After an upgrade to MacOS Catalina, I find that I can no longer install packages from source in the RStudio IDE (v1.2.5001, current stable release).

Example:

```
> install.packages("processx", type = "source")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/processx_3.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 123430 bytes (120 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 120 KB

* installing *source* package ‘processx’ ...
** package ‘processx’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang -Wall -g -O2  -Wall tools/px.c -o tools/px
make: *** [tools/px] Killed: 9
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘processx’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/processx’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/processx’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘processx’ had non-zero exit status
```

In the process I get a popup with this message:

```
“clang-4.0” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
```

It seems that RStudio is pointed at clang from XCode 11.1, rather than the clang 8 I got from CRAN https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/.

Straight from R (e.g. `sudo -i R` in my terminal) a source install works fine, so it seems to be a matter of getting RStudio to look in the right place for the clang binary.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my `~/.R/Makevars` file to point to a newer version of clang (R recommends 8+), e.g. `CC=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang`. I commented out the clang4 lines and created a new set pointing to the updated clang. Worked like a charm, now able to install R packages as usual.

Note: I had previously used brew to update llvm, which installed clang9.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer!  After posting, I played around a it with the `~/.R/Makevars` file, but with directions to the clang [suggested on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/).  Problem was that R, although using the new clang, was still pulling C libraries from Apple's Xcode, so some packages would install and others would not.  (Brew's llvm suggests setting `LDFLAGS` and CPPFLAGS`, so I did that as well.  I wonder if that's also necessary.)